# Как подружить netbeans и xdebug

Tags: php, netbeans

Такие дела:
php 5.3.8
win32
netbeans 7.1

Отладка работает, переменные внизу отслеживает. Но вот проблема в том, что переменные не изменяются в браузере. То есть страница висит и только в конце отладки выдаёт результаты. Можно ли отслеживать по мере изменения переменной результаты в браузере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чё за переменные? JavaScript? Если php, то переменные на сервере работают и в браузер не попадают.